# Adding an 'off-bounds'-label to a custom component

Tags: java, swing

I have an application for which I've created some custom drawed components inheriting from `JComponent`. These components can be dynamically added to an 'editor area' by the user. They can also be dragged around and resized in that area.

The user should be able to give those components a name, which would result in a label shown next to the component. I'm struggeling on how to achieve this, since I would prefer to not embedd this custom component in another container, just to add said label.

The easiest way that came to my mind (but unfortunately doesn't work) was to use a `JPanel` instead of a `JComponent` as superclass, add a label to it and set it's location to some negative value like `(-100, 0)`. But as you most certainly know, the `JPanel` is clipped to it's bounds, meaning the label wouldn't show.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I'm trying to do? It would seem very uncomfortable to embed my custom component in another container just for adding the label, because the original component is the only thing that is supposed to be interactive in respect of dragging, context menu etc. On the other hand redirecting mouse events from the 'real' component to the 'label container' would also seem odd...

Any ideas, insights would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: I would say your best choices are: 1- Create a new custom component which extends from your first and add this functionality in; 2- Use a container approach; 3- Use something like `TitledBorder`

Comment: Also consider tool tips.